# Load csv data into MySQL Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv, load

I am trying to load csv data into a mysql table in python:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='xuanyue', passwd='txn-data', db='eversafe_ml_dev')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('txns.csv'))
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO txn(UserID, AccountID, TransactionDate, Amount, Description, SimpleDescription, TransactionState, TransactionType, CategoryID, AcctCategoryID, CheckNum, City)"
                   "VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", row)

mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The output is:

```
File "load_data.py", line 10, in <module>
"VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", row)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ription, TransactionState, TransactionType, CategoryID, AcctCategoryID, CheckNum' at line 1")
```

I don't understand in my csv file, are the data fields all strings even if it contains transaction date, amount and etc.?

Or should I use numbers, datetime and etc in VALUES( )?

Comment: You should use data type as defined in your table. Try to make one insert by hand, then print what your are trying to execute from python and comapre.

Comment: Put `cursor.execute` inside a try catch block, then print the SQL. Try to run the SQL manually.

Comment: @beezz Thank you. If the data type is bigint(20) unsigned, what's the symbol for that?

Comment: @ismailsunni Thanks.

Comment: Formatting symbol for integers is `%d`. I think that you have problem with strings, they should be quoted `'%s'`.